# Read first 100 string array, java i/o

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was directed from to this website from a friend. The goal is to read the first 100 strings in the txt file and count how many times those words appear and print them off. 
Thank you so much in advance. I've done very well with code but this has stumped me for some reason.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Program6 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
WordAnalysis a = new WordAnalysis();
a.ReadFile();
    }}
class WordAnalysis{
    String[] coun = new String[1000];
    int[] ana = new int[100];

    void ReadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
         Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("myths.txt")); 
         int[] ana = new int[100];
         String coun = new String(); 
         String word=null;

    while(read.hasNext()) {
        word = read.next();             
        String[] arrWord = word.split(" ");
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: what is that 'some reason'?

Comment: What is your specific question? All I see are your requirements and a code dump.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please let us know what your code outputs now. Is there any error that you are getting? Or any problem in the logic?

Comment: Use a map: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Well I keep trying to store the first 100 strings and I keep failing. This reads the file but I'm having trouble storing it

Comment: So you want an array of different words and when you want to count how many times each word appears?

Comment: how can we answer if we don't know what you are asking?

Comment: Well I would guess that the last while loop would certainly lead to un-asked questions being answered.

Answer (score 3):

Procedure:

  1: Read lines [0,99] via nextLine() from Scanner

  2: Split up line with another Scanner and use next() to get each word.  Alternatively, you can use split.

  3: Put each word in a HashMap(String, Integer) where String is the word, and Integer is the number of times it has appeared

  4: Iterate through HashMap and prints out key, value pairs

Comment: Personally I prefer to give this type of pseudocode answer. +1  It encourages the OP to continue learning

Comment: @user2310289 Agreed, especially to problems like these.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, here I've used a map to keep word count.

```
    int count = 0;
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCntMap = new HashMap();
    while (read.hasNext()) {
        count++;
        word = read.next();
        String[] arrWord = word.split(" ");
        if (count == 100) {
            break;
        }
        for (String str : arrWord) {
            Integer num = wordCntMap.get(str);
            if (num == null) {
                wordCntMap.put(str, new Integer(1));
            } else {
                wordCntMap.put(str, num + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Word Count " + wordCntMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, where no answer is too stupid and no comment too thoughtless.

It seems fairly clear however that you haven't finished writing this code. :-)

Now that you have your words in arrWord, you need to start using some sort of structure that will allow you to keep track of each word and how many times its been seen.

There are plenty of containers that let you use a string as a key and an integer as a value. For your purposes it doesn't matter which one you use.

For each word in arrWord, see if you can find it in your structure (Dictionary, Hashmap, whatever). If you can't find 'word', insert a new entry of [word, 1]. If you can find 'word' then increment the counter that you find.

When you are done, all you need to do is print out the key-value pair for each entry in your structure.

HTH!

Comment: I have not thought about this comment at all.